# Linux tuning for Java Concurrent Performance

Tags: java, linux, performance, concurrency

I have a big question about tuning linux for java performance, so i start with my case.

I have an application running a number of threads that communicate with each other. My typical workflow is:

1) Some consumer thread sync on a common Object lock and calls wait() on it.
2) Some producer thread waits via Selector for data from network.
2.1) producer receives data and form an object with received timestamp (microseconds precision).
2.2) producer puts this packet in some exchange map and calls notifyAll on common lock.
3) Consumer thread wakes up and reads produced object.
3.1) consumer creates new object and writes in it time difference in microseconds between received timestamp and current timestamp. this way i can monitor reaction time.

And this reaction time is the whole issue.

When i test my application on my own machine i usually get about 200-400 microseconds reaction time, but when i monitor it on my production linux machine i get numbers from 2000 to 4000 microseconds!

Right now i'm running ubuntu 16.04 as my production OS and Oracle jdk 8-111. I have a physical server with 2 Xeon Processors. I run only usual OS daemons and my app on this server so there is plenty of resources compared to my dev notebook.

I run my java app as a jar file with flags:
sudo chrt -r 77 java -server -XX:+UseNUMA -d64 -Xmx1500m -XX:NewSize=1000m -XX:+UseG1GC -jar ...

I use sudo chrt to change priority since i thought it's the case, but it didn't help.

I tuned bios for maximum performance and turned off C-States.

What else i can tune for faster reaction times and low context switches?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no single `echo 1 > /proc/sys/unlock_concurrent_magic` option on Linux to globally improve concurrent performance. If such an option existed, it would simply be enabled by default.

In fact, despite being tunable in general, you aren't going to find many tunables that have a big effect specifically on raw concurrency on Linux. The ones that might help often *incidentially* related to concurrency - i.e., something is enabled (let's say THP) which slows down your particular load, and since at least part of the slowness occurs under lock, the whole concurrent throughput is affected.

### Java concurrency vs the OS

My experience, however, is that Java applications are **very rarely** affected directly by OS-level concurrency behavior. In fact, most of Java concurrency is implemented efficiently without using OS features, and will behave the same across OSes. The primary places where the JVM touches the OS as it relates to concurrency is for thread creation, destruction and waiting/blocking. Recent Linux kernels have very good implementations of all three so it would be unusual that you run into a bottleneck there (indeed, a well-tuned application should not be doing a ton of thread creation and should also seek to minimize blocking).

So I find it very likely the performance difference is due to other differences, in hardware, in application configuration, in the applied load, or something else.

### Characterize your performance

Here's what I'd try first to characterize the performance discrepancy between your development host and the production system.

At the top level, the difference is going either be because the production stack is **actually slower** for the load in question or because the local test isn't an **accurate reflection of the production load**.

One quick test you can do to distinguish the cases is to run whatever local test you are running to get 200-400us response times on an unloaded production server. If the server is *still* getting response times that are 10x worse, then you know your test is probably reasonable, and the difference is really in the production stack.

At that point, the problem could still be in OS, in the software configuration, in the hardware, etc. So you should try to bisect the differences between the production stack and your local host - set any tunable parameters to the same value, investigate any application-specific configuration differences, try to characterize any hardware differences.

One big gotcha is that often production servers are in multi-socket configurations, which may increase the cost of contention by an order of magnitude, since cross-socket communication (generally 100+ cycles) is required - whereas development boxes are generally multi-core but single-socket, so contention overhead is contained to the shared L3 (generally ~30 cycles).

On the other hand, you might find that your local test performs *just fine* on the production server as well, so the real issue is that your test doesn't represent the true production load. You should then make an effort to characterize the true production load so you can replicate it and then tune it locally. How to tune it locally could of course fill a book or two (or require a very highly paid contractor or two), so you'd have to come back with a narrower question to get useful help here.

### "Big Iron" vs your laptop

It is a common fallacy that "big iron" is going to be faster at everything than your puny laptop. In fact, quite the opposite is true for many operations, especially when you measure operation latency (as opposed to total throughput).

For example, latency to memory on the server parts is often 50% slower versus client parts, even comparing single socket systems. John McCalpin [reports](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/509237#comment-1785907) a main-memory latency of 54.6 ns for a client Sandy Bridge part and 79 ns for the corresponding server part. It is well known the path to memory and memory controller design for servers trades off latency for throughput, reliability and the ability to support more cores and total DRAM<sup>1</sup>.

In particular, you mention that your producer server is a "2 Xeon Processors", which I take to mean a dual-socket system. Once you introduce a second socket, you change the mechanics of synchronization entirely. On a single core system, when separate threads under contention, at worst you are sending cache lines and coherency traffic through the shared L3, which has a latency of 30-40 cycles.

On a system with more than one socket, however, concurrency traffic generally has to flow over the QPI links between sockets, which has latency on the order of DRAM access, perhaps 80 ns (i.e., 240 cycles on a 3GHz box). So you can have nearly an order of magnitude slowdown from the hardware architecture alone.

Furthermore, `notifyAll` type scenarios as you describe your workflow often get much worse with more cores and more threads. E.g., with more cores, you are less likely to have two communicating processes running on the same hyperthread (which dramatically speeds up inter-thread coordination, but is otherwise undesirable) and the total contention and coherency traffic may scale up in proportion to the number of cores (e.g., because a cache line has to ping-pong around to every core when you wake up threads).

So it's often the case that a heavily contended (often badly designed) algorithm performs much worse on "big iron" than on a single-socket consumer system.

---

<sup>1</sup> E.g., through buffering, which adds latency, but increases the host's maximum RAM capacity.

Comment: My dev notebook is 1 cpu windows and production is 2 cpu linux. I feel that my problem lies in low level OS thread management. My working threads are waking up slower and have more interrupts in linux than in windows. So i ask a general direction where i can tune this kinds of things in linux. Ideally i want my working java threads to be assigned to a free CPU core and run there without context switching by other threads.

Comment: Don't "feel". Measure.

Comment: I have measured my computation code in JMH and it runs much faster. So  when i add concurrency i get this downgrade in speed. So i post a question about tuning linux and java in regards to state changes and syncronization and how to make them faster.
My concurrency workflow i also posted in original question.
Do you have something to say on my actual question on actual tuning?

Comment: It runs "much faster than what"? I didn't say anything about the speed of your computation code. Again, you are assuming that the difference in performance is somehow due to Linux and that it can be tuned away. That is **quite unlikely** to be the case. If it is the case you can show it easily - by running the *same* program on the *same* hardware, with different OSes. If there is a 10x difference, you made a big finding and will get a lot of eyeballs on your problem.

Comment: It is entirely likely, for example, that the difference is due to hardware - you mention that your production server has "2 Xeon Processors", while your laptop is single core. This makes the server _slower_ (latency-wise) for most contended concurrent operations. I'll add more detail on that in the answer.